# Time Delay Embedding of Time Series in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have Time series data as numpy array. I want to generate Time delay embedding of data like this:

Time Series is like this:

```
    [[   1.           37.17]
     [   2.           36.99]
     [   3.           36.84]
     [   4.           37.57]
     [   5.           37.49]
     [   6.           37.45]
     [   7.           37.82]
     [   8.           37.95]
     [   9.           37.36]
     [   10.          37.84]
     [   11.           37.85]
     [   12.           37.12]]
```

Suppose my window size (w) = 4 and gap (g) = 2. We will pick every 3rd point till we get points = window size to form one 'w' dimensional point. For next 'w' dimensional point we shift the series by 1 and repeat the same process for shifted series. This will give us several 'w' dimensional points which will eventually be stored in 2D numpy array. We stop when we cant form 'w' dimensional point i.e. when we reach end of series.

Then time delay embedding for this series should be:

```
    [[ 37.17  37.57  37.82 37.84]
     [ 37.99  36.49  36.95 37.85]
     [ 37.84  37.45  36.36 37.12]]
```

We will stop at this particular point because for next point in 4 dimension we will run out of the fourth point. I have approximately 1600 points long time series and I want parameters w and g to be variable. The function will take 'w' and 'g' and time series as given and will spit out the Time Delay Embedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is to generate reindexing matrix

```py
A = np.array([ 37.17,  36.99,  36.84,  37.57,  37.49,  37.45, 
               37.82,  37.95,  37.36,  37.84,  37.85,  37.12])
w = 4
g = 2
```

Time delay embedding with `w` and `g`

```py
A[(np.arange(w)*(g+1))+ np.arange(np.max(a.shape[0] - (w-1)*(g+1), 0)).reshape(-1,1)]
```

Output:

```py
array([[ 37.17,  37.57,  37.82,  37.84],
       [ 36.99,  37.49,  37.95,  37.85],
       [ 36.84,  37.45,  37.36,  37.12]])
```

if `A` is a matrix `[index, value]` then add value column index `A[n...) ,1]`

**Update 1**

```py
# incorrect step count calculation was replaced by a.shape[0]-(w-1)*(g+1)
```

**Update 2**

```py
# added max to avoid errors on impossible values of g and w
```

---

Check documentation on used functions [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html),  [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html),  [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Hey Thanks!!, but you solution gives me index error for series with 835 length and w = 300, g = 2
Error is:
IndexError: index 837 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 835

Comment: well it is impossible values, first row will have index of 897 in last item.
i can fix it by checking %)

Comment: @avani-sharma I added `max` to avoid errors on impossible values of g and w

Comment: Yeah True that !!. I checked :) Its impossible. Well then I should be decreasing my window size.

Comment: I  did not quite understand, how are you trying to generate index for array and how it is taking care of dimension for each row. Could you please elaborate your technique?

Comment: Indexes are zero-based. So  `w` size window on firs step will be `[0,g+1,2*(g+1),..,(w-1)*(g+1)`, in movement it became matrix `[[0,..,(w-1)*(g+1)], [1,..,1+(w-1)*(g+1)], ..[n,..,n+(w-1)*(g+1)]]` where `n` is row count minus maximum window shift `rows - (w-1)*(g+1)`

First row is `(g+1)*[0,1,..w-1] ` and we populate it to the matrix by adding vector (column) `[[0,1,..,n]]`. By adding a column to a row we invoke `numpy` broadcasting mechanism. It "generates" two matrixes repeating columns and rows respectively then sums them up

Comment: Thanks :)!! Nice Explanation. I used your solution :)!!